# How to install plv8 in postgresql 14 for windows?

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I tried installing plv8 from
[1]: https://martendb.io/v3/documentation/admin/installing-plv8-windows
but it did not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is Windows and Version 14.  The solution you point to has only the files going up to PG Version 12.  It works on 12, I used that on 12.

But I am also trying to find the windows version of this extension for PG 14.  So far, people have updated the Linux builds for working with 14.

The correct, full answer is to download the source from github.
Install Version 14 of PG (You need the header files).  Install the tools spelled out in the PLV8\Windows directory README.  And then compile everything locally.  This is what the Linux users do to get the binaries for their specific system.
we are grabbing the source from here: https://github.com/plv8/plv8/tree/master

We are working on this right now.  We will push the compiled (under windows 10 x64) Versions up to another GIT and publish the link for others as our way of supporting this.  (But it's not trivial, this stuff is made more for the Linux side of things)